# Inner Join On (Hive) gives different result than PySpark Inner Join

Tags: pyspark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I observed this phenomenon today. When I execute the following command in Hive CLI, I obtains something different than by doing this with pyspark :

Hive :

```
Select count(distinct t1.fieldX) from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.fieldX=t2.fieldX AND t1.fieldY=t2.fieldY);
```

Result : 17 488

SparkSQL :

```
hc.sql("Select count(distinct t1.fieldX) from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.fieldX==t2.fieldX AND t1.fieldY==t2.fieldY)")
```

Result : 5555

I obtain the same result using this code :

```
tabl1.alias("t1").join(
    other=table2.alias("t2"),
    on=[t1.fieldX==t2.fieldX, t1.fieldY==t2.fieldY]
    how='inner'
    ).select("fieldX").distinct().count()
```

Result : 5555

I don't get why I obtain different results !

Comment: can you try a simple count with hive and spark to be sure you're on the same tables ?

Comment: Yeah I've already checked that, I'm even obtaining the same result when I just put only 1 condition. But when I'm trying to join with both condition I have this issue.